# NumPy for dommies using Jupyter

Tags: numpy, anaconda

I am learning how to use NumPy now and after cerating a 1 dim ndarray like this :

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1.5, 2.3, 4, 5.8], dtype = np.int64)
```

## when printing x:

print(x)
the **dtype = np.int64** does not work in the web base **Jupyter notebook** (Anaconda), can someone help me please? Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Can you please show the actual error message that you get? Does this also happen in IPython or the regular Python interpreter? Please see the [How To Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help improving the question.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work, do you mean it still print floats?

Comment: Soory Guys, Ignore me please. I was dumb